# castle windsor, which dll folder I should use?

Tags: reference, castle-windsor

I download the latest copy of castle windsor.  there are 2 folders, one is net40, another one is net40-client.  which one I should use for  my asp.net mvc3 application.  I am using vs2010.

the tutorial I read from the castle windsor wiki web site tells me to use dll files in "net40" .

if I use NeGet to install the package.  I notice It only has net40-client folder.

can some one please explain to me the difference between those 2 folders and which one I should use.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I think that net40 and net40-client are basically the same except the later does not depend on `System.Web` and, therefore does not have the per web request lifestyle.

I found this post that confirms that (kind of - it would be great if there were a definitive page somewhere that outlines the differences but I could not find one):  http://www.mail-archive.com/castle-project-users@googlegroups.com/msg09398.html

Given you are in asp .net anyway I would suggest you went with the net40 version (as you will already be building against that profile).